# Как исключить ложные срабатывания без потери быстродействия

Tags: python-3.x, алгоритм, numpy, opencv

В моей программе довольно часто бывают ложные срабатывания и мне как-то надо сделать фильтрацию изображения, чтобы их не было и без большой потери производительности.

```
edges = edges[y1:y1 + 17, x1:x1 + 17] # Это коодринаты области, за которой нужно наблюдать
if numpy.sum(edges) > edges_count:
    ... 
    # Если будет больше заданного количества пикселей, то делает определенные действия
    # У меня 4 области, за которыми нужно следить, это происходит ассинхронно и для каждой области свой порог пикселей
```

Я думаю, что мне нужно размыть изображение. Знаю есть такой метод в opencv-python, но он вроде медленный. А если ставить пороговое значение больше, то не обнаруживает объект (обнаруживает, но не все его разновидности).

Comment: в математических вычислениях asyncio?

Comment: нет, определение области происходит ассинхронно

Comment: асинхронно и асинкио - это разные штуки)

Comment: Что представляет собой edges? Откуда оно берется изначально?